# Android HTTP listener

Tags: android, http, listener

I have to solve a project to do. In my android project I have to listen http get calls.

I am not going to send get requests with http. I will accept get requests, so according to the number of accept calls, I will implement my coding.

In order to do that, Do I have to embed a server to my application or , Is there a more simple way to achieve this.

Could anyone explain; which tool can be easier to accept http get calls in android development environment.

Comment: Yes. If you want to receive http calls then you have to implement an http server on your device. Only calls to your server will come in. And only if your device is on wifi and the used router forwards the request. Who gave you this task?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem Nanohttpd. It is a server, you can embed into your application. It has easy installation with gradle. Thanks for the help.